# SELECT issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to perform a `SELECT` but I am not able to retrieve the data I want.

I have tried lots of sentences without success, so that's why I am exposing here the whole problem.

Here is my database (four tables):

```
-- Table users
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id VARCHAR(15),
    private_user_id VARCHAR(16),
    public_user_id VARCHAR(16)
);

-- Table events
CREATE TABLE events (
    event_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    public_event_id VARCHAR(8),
    ref_user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    name VARCHAR(64),
    description VARCHAR(256)
);

-- Table proposals
CREATE TABLE proposals (
    proposal_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    public_proposal_id VARCHAR(8),
    ref_event_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES events(event_id),
    proposal_date VARCHAR(32),
    proposal_location VARCHAR(64),
    proposal_type INT
);

-- Table responses
CREATE TABLE responses (
    response_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ref_user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
    ref_proposal_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES proposals(proposal_id),
    user_name VARCHAR(32),
    response INT
);
```

There are users. There are events. Events are created by one user. Events have proposals. Proposals have responses from the users. I need:

> I need to achieve this given a private user id. Is something like: given
>   the private user id, analyze the responses of that user, so analyze
>   the proposals of that responses, and finally get the events of that
>   responses, RETURNING THE PUBLIC USER ID of the creator of each event.

I have tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT events.ref_user_id, public_event_id, name, description, public_user_id
FROM events, users, proposals, responses
WHERE responses.ref_user_id = user_id
  AND private_user_id = 'lk0X3lOQl972U7pB'
```

but the public_user_id retrieved is the user that has responded, while I need the event creator.

Comment: Start with one table. Then JOIN another table ON to that. Then JOIN another table ON to the first and/or the second table. Then... do you see where I'm going with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ALL                                    -- show all
    u.pulic_user_id AS creator_pulic_user_id, -- creators' public IDs
    e.name          AS event_name             -- and events' names
FROM                                          -- from
    events AS e                               -- events
  JOIN                                        -- and
    users AS u                                -- their creator 
      ON e.ref_user_id = u.user_id
WHERE                                         -- where
    EXISTS                                    -- exists
    ( SELECT 1                                -- a
      FROM responses AS r                     -- response
        JOIN users AS ur                      -- by a user,
          ON ur.user_id = r.ref_user_id
        JOIN proposals AS p                   -- for a proposal
          ON p.proposal_id = r.ref_proposal_id 
      WHERE p.ref_event_id = e.event_id       -- that is about that event
        AND ur.private_user_id = @X           -- and the responding user  
    ) ;                                       -- has private ID = @X
```

---

**Sidenote**: Inline foreign key constraints, like this:

```
ref_user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(user_id),
```

are parsed (only for syntax correctness) and **ignored** in MySQL. You have to add them in the end of a `CREATE TABLE` statement to be valid and enforced. Or use `ALTER TABLE`, if you have already inserted data in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the ids that are wrong it's because you're returning public_user_id from the user table, you want `events.ref_user_id`, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT events.ref_user_id AS public_user_id , public_event_id, name, description
FROM events, users, proposals, responses 
WHERE (responses.ref_user_id = user_id 
  AND ref_proposal_id = proposal_id AND ref_event_id = event_id)
```

**Edit**

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ref_user_id AS public_user_id 
FROM events e, users u, proposals p, responses r
WHERE r.ref_user_id = u.user_id 
  AND r.ref_proposal_id = p.proposal_id 
  AND p.ref_event_id = e.event_id
  AND u.private_user_id = 'lk0X3lOQl972U7pB'
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please read the edited question, in the bottom.

Comment: OK! We are near the solution. With that sentence, I am retrieving the user_id of the user that created the event. BUT, I need the public_user_id of that user, which is a field of the users table.

Comment: To do that you could JOIN the user table a second time to calculate it, or use a subselect. But I actual thing that ypercube has a better answer, it has clearer logic and is probably faster than adapting my version.